# Error calling API from .net "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: .net, api, webrequest

I'm getting the error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" from the code below when calling certain APIs (it works for some APIs) but only when run from a Windows 2012 server. It works fine on my laptop. The other thing I have found is I can call the failing APIs fine from Postman from the server but if I use Powershell it fails.

It seems to be something related to .Net but I have tried updating to .Net 4.8 without any success.

Any thoughts on what else to try?

```
Console.WriteLine("Make Reuest Starting");
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(generalConfig?.ProxyAddress))
            {
                WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(generalConfig.ProxyAddress);
                webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(generalConfig.ProxyUsername, generalConfig.ProxyPassword,
                    generalConfig.ProxyDomain);
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;
            }
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(apiUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Timeout = 40000;

            if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)))
            {
               
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Pre web request log");
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    //Console.WriteLine(responseData);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Windows Server 2012 is long out of support and *didn't* support TLS1.2 out of the box. You need to patch the server to allow TLS1.2 . Enabling weak algorithms is not a solution. TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are obsolete and most likely disabled (eg through Group policies), so your client application won't use them to connect.

Comment: The server is patched and TLS1.2 is enabled. Doesn't this line `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;` mean the highest version of TLS supported on the server will be used?

Comment: No, it means weak and disabled algorithms will be attempted. Since 4.6.2 .NET will use the best algorithms provided by the OS.